# Shortest quine in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, quine

What's the shortest [quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)) written in Kotlin language?

See my implementation in answers, but I believe a shorter one exists.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf Stack Exchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Here is a straightforward implementation in kotlin script:

```
val a="val a=%c%s%c%nprint(a.format(34,a,34))"
print(a.format(34,a,34))
```

Tested with:

```sh
$ kotlinc -script quine.kts > out.kts
$ diff -s quine.kts out.kts
Files quine.kts and out.kts are identical
```

Number of chars:

```
$ stat quine.kts
Size: 71
```